# SQL - Different "ORDER BY" values for the same field

Tags: mysql, sql

The following code is producing a list with the non-expired rows on top, then the ones with unknown expiry date and at the end the already expired (all of them in ascending order). The problem is that I want the last block of already expired rows to be in descending order so it displays the rows that expired more recently on top of that block without altering the order of the other top blocks.

Basically, I am trying to find a way to incorporate two "ORDER BY" clauses within the same recordset...

Any ideas? Thanks

```
SELECT *
  FROM prueba 
 WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(Company,Deal,keywords,Type,Expiry,Name)) LIKE UPPER(%s) 
ORDER BY (CASE 
            WHEN prueba.Expiry = 'UNKNOWN' THEN 1 
            WHEN prueba.Expiry < CURRENT_DATE THEN 2 
          END)
       , prueba.Expiry ASC
```

Comment: What data type is Expiry? What's the format?

Comment: So what's the problem? Why doesn't your query work?

Comment: Its date. The format is year-month-day (e.g. 2012-12-14)

Comment: Currently I'm getting something like this:

2012-12-15
2012-12-15
2012-12-16
2012-12-22

UNKNOWN
UNKNOWN

2012-11-25
2012-11-29
2012-12-12
2012-12-13

But I would like to get this instead:

2012-12-15
2012-12-15
2012-12-16
2012-12-22

UNKNOWN
UNKNOWN

2012-12-13
2012-12-12
2012-11-29
2012-11-25

Comment: if that column is date, why are you checking 'unknown' string value?

Comment: And you need the dates in DESCENDING order, but you're using ASC in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/618f3/22)

```
SELECT * FROM t
order by case 
      when expiry = 'Unknown' Then 1 
      WHEN expiry >= CURRENT_DATE THEN 0 
      ELSE 2 END,
CASE WHEN expiry >= CURRENT_DATE THEN expiry END,
CASE WHEN expiry < CURRENT_DATE THEN expiry END desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate those records that have expired into another `SELECT` clause, then `UNION ALL`:

```
(SELECT *
FROM prueba
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(Company,Deal,keywords,Type,Expiry,Name)) LIKE UPPER(%s)
AND prueba.Expiry > CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY prueba.Expiry DESC)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM prueba
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(Company,Deal,keywords,Type,Expiry,Name)) LIKE UPPER(%s)
AND prueba.Expiry = 'UNKNOWN')
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM prueba
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(Company,Deal,keywords,Type,Expiry,Name)) LIKE UPPER(%s)
AND prueba.Expiry < CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY prueba.Expiry DESC)
```

Comment: You can of course change the `ORDER BY` clause to be `ASC` or `DESC` in each `SELECT` to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I put it in but I'm getting this in return: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT * FROM prueba WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(Company,Deal,keywords,Type,Expiry,Name)' at line 6

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause, but I left out a `UNION ALL`. Try again with the latest edit?